# C++ dictionary trie implementation

Tags: c++, dictionary, trie

I am getting a segfault in my `insert` function on the line:

```
current->isWord = true;
```

Everything compiles fine with no warnings or errors (`g++ -Wall -Wextra`).  My `main` function just calls the `insert` function once and it won't work.  Here is my code; it is a hybrid between my `.h` and `.cpp` file:

```
const int alphabetSize = 26;

struct Node
{
    bool isWord;
    Node* child[alphabetSize];
};

Dictionary::Dictionary()
{
    initNode(head); //Node* head; is defined in my .h file under private:
}

bool Dictionary::isPrefix(string s)
{
    Node* current = endOfString(s, false);
    if (current == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}

bool Dictionary::isWord(string s)
{
    Node* current = endOfString(s, false);
    if (current == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return current->isWord;
    }
}

void Dictionary::insert(string s)
{
    Node* current = endOfString(s, true);
    current->isWord = true; //segfault here
}

//initializes a new Node
void Dictionary::initNode(Node* current)
{
    current = new Node;
    current->isWord = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < alphabetSize; i++)
    {
       current->child[i] = NULL;
    }
}

//returns a pointer to the Node of the last character in the string
//isInsert tells it whether it needs to initialize new Nodes
Node* Dictionary::endOfString(string s, bool isInsert)
{
    Node* current = head;
    Node* next = head;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    {
        if (isalpha(s[i]) == true)
        {
            int letter = (tolower(s[i]) - 'a');
            next = current->child[letter];
            if (next == NULL)
            {
                if (isInsert == false)
                {
                    return NULL;
                }

                initNode(next);
                current->child[letter] = next;
            }
            current = current->child[letter];
        }
    }

    return current;
}
```

Comment: Why there is no NULL check in `insert()`?

Comment: @iammilind: Because it's passing `true` to `endOfString` rather than `false` like the other times.

Comment: @icktoofay, what happens if the `head` is NULL and `s.length() = 0` in `Dictionary::endOfString(..)` method? We need to have NULL check in that condition as well.

Comment: @iammilind: `head` won't be `NULL` if `initNode` is fixed; `initNode` is called in the constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`initNode` creates a new `Node` and initializes it, but it is then discarded. Because `current` is passed by value, when it is modified inside of the function, the changes do not propagate outside of `initNode`. The straightforward fix is to make it pass by reference:

```
void Dictionary::initNode(Node*& current)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
//initializes a new Node
void Dictionary::initNode(Node* current)
{
    current = new Node;
    current->isWord = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < alphabetSize; i++)
    {
       current->child[i] = NULL;
    }
}
```

`current` is passed in by value, so when you alter `current` in the method you are altering a copy of what was passed in, not the exterior variable. Try passing in a `Node** current` that is a pointer to your pointer so you can edit the original variable. You would call it like this; `initNode(&next);` and in the method you would dereference current to be able to edit the original variable.